# Creating Highlighted PDF from JSON

Tags: pdf, syntax-highlighting

I have a JSON file and would like to create a pdf containing the pretty printed and syntax highlighted version of that JSON file.

Is there any way to do that in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will require a few steps but everything can be done using the command line:

1. Install the following dependencies:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install aha wkhtmltopdf python-pygments
   ```
2. Prettify your json file:

   ```
   cat foo.json | python -m json.tool > bar.json
   ```
3. Call `pygmentize` to get syntax highlighting and export it to html with `aha`:

   ```
   pygmentize bar.json | aha > bar.html
   ```
4. Finally export the html to pdf with `wkhtmltopdf`:

   ```
   wkhtmltopdf bar.html foo.pdf
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can actually do this with Gedit, the default text editor Ubuntu ships with. Simply open up your file in Gedit and make sure it's properly syntax-highlighted. Then go to *File* → *Print* and select *Print to File* as the printer and *PDF* as the output format. This should result in a properly syntax-highlighted PDF file.

For other more scriptable solutions make sure to check out [this unix.SE Q&A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20446/syntax-highlight-source-file-lpr).